# SimpledateFormat Parsing

Tags: java

Whenever I am going to parse date i am unable to get date in yyyy-MM-dd Format.

Below is my Code

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Demo d=new Demo();
        System.out.println(d.getDate1("2011-08-11"));
    }
    public Date getDate1(String pValue) throws Exception{
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return dateFormat.parse(pValue);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
 Thu Aug 11 00:00:00 IST 2011.
```

Here I am converting String data format to Date Format.

Comment: _i am unable to get date in required Format_ whats your format?

Comment: actually i am passing String data in yyyy-MM-dd and i need date Object of this format.

Comment: date in java also contains the hour, minute, second and millisecond. when you are printing it back you didn't format it to print only the year month and day so it gets a default format. IST is the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

When you print your date object like this:

```
System.out.println(d.getDate1("2011-08-11"));
```

then you just call the default `toString()` method of date.
If you want to print the formatted date, then you should use your date formatter.
Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse("2011-08-11")));
    }
}
```

Comment: But i Need it in Date Object.

Comment: The Date object does not contain the format of the date, just a timestamp.
If you want to print it formatted you should use a formatter like my example.

Answer (score 0):

The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision. When you are printing it you didn't format it to print only the year month and day so it gets a default format. IST is the timezone.